# GeoServer 2.5 returns GetFeatureInfo featureMember geometry as lat long rather than projected

Tags: geoserver, wms

We are using GeoServer 2.1 to display data that is stored in Oracle sdo_geometry.  The data is stored in Irish Transverse Mercator (EPSG:2157) and we want display it on a map in that projection.
With release 2.1.0 we are making the following GetFeatureInfo request when a user clicks on the map:

```
http://<server>:8080/geoserver/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&LAYERS=TownlandLayer&QUERY_LAYERS=TownlandLayer&STYLES=,,,&BBOX=618565.0,707446.2,620258.3,708216.1&FEATURE_COUNT=10&HEIGHT=582&WIDTH=1280&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&INFO_FORMAT=application/vnd.ogc.gml&SRS=EPSG:2157&X=587&Y=354
```

This returns the id of the feature clicked on, plus the geometry as GML (in EPSG:2157 coordinates) so we can highlight the feature on the map.

This all works perfectly.

This week we upgraded to GeoServer 2.5 and now the same query returns the geometry in lat long rather than in EPSG:2157.  As far as I can see the layers are configured exactly the same on both GeoServer instances and they are both feeding off the same database.

We're a bit lost on this.  Any ideas why we're now getting the geometry back as lat/long rather than EPSG:2157?

Thanks in advance,
John

Here's a sample response from GeoServer 2.1 (good):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wfs:FeatureCollection xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns:PRAI="http://test.org" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://test.org http://172.16.25.35:8080/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&amp;version=1.0.0&amp;request=DescribeFeatureType&amp;typeName=PRAI%3ATownlandLayer http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://172.16.25.35:8080/geoserver/schemas/wfs/1.0.0/WFS-basic.xsd">
    <gml:boundedBy>
        <gml:null>unknown</gml:null>
    </gml:boundedBy>
    <gml:featureMember>
        <TESTWS:TownlandLayer fid="TownlandLayer.fid-3171d85a_14502e9da6f_48b9">
            <TESTWS:ID>301696</TESTWS:ID>
            <TESTWS:GEOMETRY>
                <gml:Polygon srsName="http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#2157">
                    <gml:outerBoundaryIs>
                        <gml:LinearRing>
                            <gml:coordinates xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" decimal="." cs="," ts=" ">619334.56663122,707639.08780444 619336.865,707641.322 619340.052,707647.078 619354.642,707660.683 619381.414,707688.036 619392.126,707699.266 619400.658,707709.432 619403.251,707716.158 619416.594,707738.985 619445.052,707791.344 619460.49,707818.32 619481.58,707791.968 619490.752,707780.312 619512.212,707754.921 619521.525,707758.33 619523.334,707758.434 619527.772,707756.102 619533.291,707753.399 619536.422,707753.129 619546.07,707753.642 619562.612,707756.743 619577.952,707760.216 619591.012,707764.795 619598.119,707764.368 619618.689,707725.913 619628.925,707707.069 619642.69,707683.799 619659.583,707707.813 619678.88,707730.142 619690.941,707744.223 619697.976,707750.862 619702.657,707755.319 619705.456,707758.187 619709.72,707763.089 619715.228,707772.077 619729.536,707794.243 619715.458,707822.699 619704.511,707851.006 619696.62,707870.846 619686.496,707896.855 619679.904,707913.911 619675.315,707925.887 619672.516,707934.388 619641.547,707929.999 619585.257,707919.482 619518.407,707903.814 619515.202,707906.979 619496.617,707957.979 619481.258,708003.14 619474.046,708032.44 619474.921,708041.108 619471.385,708061.448 619467.113,708081.788 619417.611,708070.788 619374.539,708060.065 619350.628,708055.386 619327.664,708049.547 619304.444,708045.087 619283.454,708040.441 619276.024,708058.095 619273.661,708058.722 619269.497,708059.5395 619264.539,708032.441 619262.7349,708022.932 619249.249,707951.851 619244.598,707924.334 619232.881,707865.048 619229.994,707848.444 619228.9681,707842.7894 619222.356,707806.345 619221.5878,707802.284 619214.3036,707763.7754 619214.236,707763.418 619204.051,707702.811 619192.533,707645.805 619191.526,707641.056 619198.626,707636.88 619225.122,707611.926 619235.35728196,707601.60979202 619303.61998552,707668.89537381 619334.56663122,707639.08780444</gml:coordinates>
                        </gml:LinearRing>
                    </gml:outerBoundaryIs>
                </gml:Polygon>
            </TESTWS:GEOMETRY>
        </TESTWS:TownlandLayer>
    </gml:featureMember>
</wfs:FeatureCollection>
```

Here's a sample response from GeoServer 2.5 (bad):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wfs:FeatureCollection xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns:PRAI="http://test.org" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://test.org http://geoserver2:8080xx/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&amp;version=1.0.0&amp;request=DescribeFeatureType&amp;typeName=PRAI%3ATownlandLayer http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://geoserver2:8080xx/geoserver/schemas/wfs/1.0.0/WFS-basic.xsd">
    <gml:boundedBy>
        <gml:null>unknown</gml:null>
    </gml:boundedBy>
    <gml:featureMember>
        <TESTWS:TownlandLayer fid="TownlandLayer.fid--1b39d662_14502ea1e37_-6026">
            <TESTWS:ID>301696</TESTWS:ID>
            <TESTWS:GEOMETRY>
                <gml:Polygon srsName="http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#2157">
                    <gml:outerBoundaryIs>
                        <gml:LinearRing>
                            <gml:coordinates xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" decimal="." cs="," ts=" ">-2.66585979,99.44142269 -0.63895079,97.47110743 2.1716334,92.39494721 15.038412,80.39683049 38.64837751,56.27448675 48.09518576,46.37085935 55.61947329,37.40556317 57.90621468,31.47396941 69.67327615,11.34306089 94.7701086,-34.8318302 108.38473012,-58.62170132 126.98379528,-35.3821297 135.07249256,-25.10281706 153.99785711,-2.71074197 162.21090092,-5.7171058 163.80624036,-5.80882239 167.72006925,-3.75225435 172.58722148,-1.36850503 175.34841982,-1.13039466 183.85689686,-1.58280436 198.44512521,-4.31754599 211.97332149,-7.3803508 223.49080802,-11.41852621 229.75840196,-11.04195907 247.8988842,22.87113012 256.92591269,39.4894698 269.06513184,60.01105569 283.96290367,38.83334346 300.98073963,19.14161629 311.61721781,6.72371982 317.82131565,0.86885051 321.94944386,-3.06173429 324.41785465,-5.5909955 328.17823463,-9.91402146 333.03568607,-17.84045094 345.65377162,-37.38843 333.23852083,-62.48349868 323.58446837,-87.44716571 316.62547249,-104.94386808 307.6972157,-127.88095134 301.88379523,-142.92247127 297.83680092,-153.48398879 295.36839014,-160.98093772 268.0571313,-157.11032146 218.41552969,-147.8354818 159.46116715,-134.01802552 156.63470893,-136.80920813 140.24477882,-181.78561038 126.69982663,-221.61265552 120.33963422,-247.45203956 121.11128818,-255.09626416 117.99292429,-273.03391165 114.22548918,-290.97155914 70.57015852,-281.2707665 32.58538211,-271.81425745 11.49850458,-267.68789301 -8.75322289,-262.5385359 -29.23071426,-258.60530543 -47.7415904,-254.50804337 -54.29403488,-270.07693368 -56.37794152,-270.62987886 -60.05013248,-271.35082413 -64.42254429,-247.45292145 -66.01356247,-239.06702716 -77.90664606,-176.38138699 -82.00831756,-152.11441325 -92.34142551,-99.83066846 -94.88744263,-85.18776291 -95.79217383,-80.20102636 -101.62332028,-48.06106569 -102.30078836,-44.47970942 -108.72465325,-10.51935092 -117.76632112,43.24455845 -127.92393291,93.51759348 -128.81199638,97.70569023 -122.55057568,101.38846388 -99.18401188,123.39515293 -90.15761661,132.49291607 -29.95740459,73.15441817 -2.66585979,99.44142269</gml:coordinates>
                        </gml:LinearRing>
                    </gml:outerBoundaryIs>
                </gml:Polygon>
            </TESTWS:GEOMETRY>
        </TESTWS:TownlandLayer>
    </gml:featureMember>
</wfs:FeatureCollection>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question has just been answered on the GeoServer mailing list:

http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/GeoServer-2-5-returns-GetFeatureInfo-featureMember-geometry-as-lat-long-rather-than-projected-td5131739.html

Simone.

Answer (score 1):

As Simone mentioned, the question was answered on the GeoServer mailing list courtesy of Ing. Andrea Aime.

I have set the following in the JVM startup parameters:
-Dorg.geoserver.wms.featureinfo.render.enabled=false
And the GeoFeatureInfo is back working as before.